# What could cause the use of hashtags to work and html5 mode not?

Tags: angularjs, html, hashtag, angular-routing

Assuming you have `<a href="#/sign-in">Link</a>` and it works fine out of the box with `$routeProvider` in your config, what could cause enabling html5 mode to not work? Assuming you have `<base href="/"` set in the `head` and rewrote the `href` as "sign-in" instead of "#/sign-in".

Comment: Are you calling `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` at your module config?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by html5 mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your server isn't configured to forward all requests back to `index.html`
You can read about configuration here:  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: This has nothing to do with the server.  I am clicking on the navigation link that angular is supposed to handle.  In other words, angular needs to capture the click event before the browser does and navigate without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, an anchor `href` link needs to be inside a controller to work properly with html5 mode. After adding the same link inside a controller (it was just inside `ng-app`), it worked as planned. This is poorly documented and I hope this helps someone.